# How do I fix the package testing error Julia?

Tags: package, julia

When I test the NTFk package with command `Pkg.test("NTFK")`. I'm getting the below error.

> ERROR: LoadError: Some tests did not pass: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0
> errored, 0 broken. in expression starting at
> C:\Users\lff19.julia\packages\NTFk\bvyOe\test\runtests.jl:17 ERROR:
> Package NTFk errored during testing

Comment: Impossible to tell without more context, but I would open an issue at the repository instead of asking here.

Comment: A Pkg testing error is something for the maintainers to fix, either in the package or in the test itself. Since you've already [opened an issue](https://github.com/TensorDecompositions/NTFk.jl/issues/23) about this, there's nothing more to do on your side. (Unless you're able to look into the issue and contribute a fix, which I'm sure would also be very welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

For Test.jl, the package scans for ~/PACKAGENAME/test/runtests.jl

A "passed" test is self-explanitory.

A "failed" test means a test resulted in an unexpected value.

An "errored" test means the test was not able to be executed, it errored instead.

A "broken" test refers to a known failing test. Setting the test to "broken" means it will ignore the "fail" status.

So, the 1 failing test is just a single fail in the project's runtest.jl file. It is not a problem with your Pkg.test("NTFK") command, it is a problem within the source code. It should be relatively simple to figure out which test fails from the error/ your console's output.

Realistically, it should be the developer's responsibility to fix the testcase. Although, you could just as well "dev" the package( ] dev PACKAGENAME), effectively making yourself the maintainer for your local package, and going into the runtests.jl and fixing it yourself. Note that "dev"ing a package will move it to ~/.julia/dev .